# Excel VBA Copy Rows between Blanks

Tags: excel

I have no experience of VBA, and i'm trying to understand if i can get it to run something for me in Excel.

I have a dataset of assemblies, with parts underneath, the system can only pull it in one full dataset from the top assembly, down to the bottom (326 assemblies).

I need a solution that copies the rows of the assemblies into a new sheet, so i have a tab for each assembly.

[image: Dataset example]

The following code i've picked up:

```
Sub Star123()
   Dim rownum As Long
   Dim colnum As Long
   Dim startrow As Long
   Dim endrow As Long
   Dim lastrow As Long
   rownum = 1
   colnum = 1
   lastrow = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
   With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("a1:a" & lastrow)


   For rownum = 1 To lastrow
    Do
       If .Cells(rownum, 1).Value = "Start" Then
          startrow = rownum
       End If

       rownum = rownum + 1


   If (rownum > lastrow) Then Exit For

   Loop Until .Cells(rownum, 1).Value = "End"
   endrow = rownum
   rownum = rownum + 1


   Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(startrow & ":" & endrow).Copy

   Set newSht = Sheets.Add
   Range("A1").Select
   ActiveSheet.Paste


   Next rownum
End With
End Sub
```

However this just runs the wole dataset, i need to understand how the loop can separate into new sheets.

Comment: Do you want to copy the cells between "Start" and "End" into separate sheets?

Comment: Your code doesn't actually paste anything. What determines the destination sheet?

Comment: Sorry, missed a bit of my code. I have    Set newSht = Sheets.Add
   Range("A1").Select
   ActiveSheet.Paste as the paste function, ive added above. I want to copy the cells between start and end into seprate sheets, there are 325 occurrences of start and end. Originally the data comes with blanks in between assemblies, but i couldn't sort my code to filter between the blanks so ended up with start and end, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. I've added a few comments.

The main problem with your code was only the single line indicated, which was skipping the next "Start".

The code could be simplified if each "Start" always occurs immediately after "End".

```
Sub Star123()

Dim rownum As Long
Dim colnum As Long
Dim startrow As Long
Dim endrow As Long
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim newSht As Worksheet

rownum = 1
colnum = 1
lastrow = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'better than hardcoding 65336 which won't work for recent versions of xl anyway

With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("a1:a" & lastrow)
    For rownum = 1 To lastrow
        Do
            If .Cells(rownum, 1).Value = "Start" Then
                startrow = rownum
            End If
            rownum = rownum + 1
            If (rownum > lastrow) Then Exit For
        Loop Until .Cells(rownum, 1).Value = "End"
        endrow = rownum
        'rownum = rownum + 1 'just needed to comment out this line as it was skipping the next Start
        Set newSht = Sheets.Add
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(startrow & ":" & endrow).Copy newSht.Range("A1") 'reference sheet directly without selecting or activating
    Next rownum
End With

End Sub
```